# Tabulator Remote/Ajax Sorting

Tags: tabulator, directus

I am working with Tabulator on with an ajaxURL and I have remote pagination working, but am struggling with the sorting. The format needs to be changed to be compatible with Directus which is pretty simple. Rather than "asc" and "desc" it is formatted like:

```
&sort[]=field_to_sort
&sort[]=-field_to_sort
```

It seems pretty straight forward, but I can't get the dir=asc/desc to get replaced. I've tried:

```
dataSendParams: {
    "page":"page",
    "size":"limit",
    "sort":"sort[]=",
    "dir":"-"
},
```

but no dice.  I include the params in the ajaxURLGenerator, but with the wrong format it doesn't really do me much good. I have found lots of talk, but I have yes to see a concrete resolution to this. Even the dataSendParams has been just trial ansd error since there is no documentation on it specifically.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.